# Can rsync store wildcard names (perhaps using a variable)?

Tags: rsync

I'm copying files from one machine to another.  Machine A has files in:

```
/usr/a/foo/*
/usr/b/foo/*
/usr/c/foo/*
/usr/d/foo/*
```

Machine B wants these files in:

```
/foo-1.2.3/usr/a/*
/foo-1.2.3/usr/b/*
/foo-1.2.3/usr/c/*
/foo-1.2.3/usr/d/*
```

I can flatten the structure using `rsync -ae ssh user@remote:/var/*/foo/ /foo-1.2.3/var/`, and I can separately copy each of the four directories, but I can't figure out if it's possible to do this in a single command without resorting to an outside helper (awk, sed, perl...).

Note that this is sheer curiosity at this point, as it has taken longer to figure this out than it already took to do four separate copies.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with include/exclude rules. Something like (untested):

```
rsync -a --include=*/foo/*** --exclude=* user@remote:/usr/ /foo-1.2.3/usr
```

The `***` is introduced in `rsync 2.6.7`. Without it, you need one include for the directory (`foo/`) and another for the contents (`foo/**`). Note that when you use an include like this, you need to have a suitably broad exclude as the last rule since everything is included be default and files are included/excluded according to the first match in the list of rules (putting `--exclude=*` first won't copy anything).